# sorted combo box and reassigning the datasource

Tags: c#, combobox, datasource, sorting

**Background:**
There are two combo boxes that differ only in the Sorted property.  comboBox1 has the Sorted property set to *true* and comboBox2 has the Sorted property set to *false*.  When attempting to reassign/reset the datasource property of these two combo boxes, comboBox1 displays no data and comboBox2 does.  Why does the Sorted property prevent comboBox1 from displaying its' data properly?

All code included below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string[] a8BitGames = { "Metroid", "Zelda", "Phantasy Star", "SB:S&SEP" };
    private string[] a16BitGames = { "StarFox", "Link", "Final Fantasy", "Altered Beast" };
    private List<string> lSomeList = null;
    private List<string> lSomeOtherList = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.lSomeList = new List<string>(a8BitGames);
        this.lSomeOtherList = new List<string>(a16BitGames);
        this.comboBox1.DataSource = lSomeList;
        this.comboBox2.DataSource = lSomeOtherList;
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.IndexChanged(1);
    }

    private void IndexChanged(int comboBox)
    {
        this.comboBox1.DataSource = null;
        this.comboBox1.DataSource = a16BitGames;

        this.comboBox2.DataSource = null;
        this.comboBox2.DataSource = a8BitGames;
    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.IndexChanged(2);
    }
}

partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.comboBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.comboBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // comboBox1
        // 
        this.comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.comboBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
        this.comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
        this.comboBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);
        this.comboBox1.Sorted = true;
        this.comboBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
        // 
        // comboBox2
        // 
        this.comboBox2.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.comboBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 41);
        this.comboBox2.Name = "comboBox2";
        this.comboBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);
        this.comboBox2.TabIndex = 1;
        this.comboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
        this.Controls.Add(this.comboBox2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.comboBox1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox comboBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox comboBox2;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to reassign datasource in Index changed?

Comment: @Sriram, this is example code.  In the actual program I am managing a common set of values across multiple combo boxes and no two combo boxes can select the same value.  Whenever an index is changed I remove the new indexed item from the list and add the old one.  This way the new indexed item is removed as a selection from the other combo boxes and the old indexed item is added as a selection.  Not sure that is relevant to question though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you accidentally hiding an exception?  According to MSDN you will receive an "ArgumentException" when "An attempt was made to sort a ComboBox that is attached to a data source."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.sorted.aspx

Comment: I agree, but no, I am not hiding the exception, I never seem to get it.  I wonder if defaulting the property to true somehow prevents the exception from ever being raised...

Comment: It is hiding an exeception because when you try to set the comboBox1.Sorted = false and then back to true it comes with an error: ComboBox that has a DataSource set cannot be sorted. Sort the data using the underlying data model.

Comment: HighExodus not so much defaulting, but more the fact that when you set sorted, the item isn't a Data-Bound control (yet). Try setting this.comboBox1.Sorted = true; at the end of your IndexChanged(...) method, and I'm betting you'll see the exception.

Comment: @PaulZaczkowski, I follow your reasoning (and agree with it), but why does the initial assignment of the datasource work as expected?

Comment: HighExodus I'm not sure if you've stumbled across a bug, or we're both missing something here.  It would seem you cannot alter the DataSource of the sorted ComboBox after your initial loading.  Also, the lack of exception here is very strange indeed.  Perhaps someone else has some more insight :/

Comment: @PaulZaczkowski, thanks for the input!  Something tells me this is a "feature" of .NET.  Unfortunately for me, it took a fair amount of time to understand what was happening...

Answer (score 1):

Try to sort by sorting the list on setting the DataSource

```
 public List<string> A16Games
 {
    get { return this.a16BitGames.OrderBy(x => x).ToList(); }
 }

 public List<string> A8Games
 {
    get { return this.a8BitGames.OrderBy(x => x).ToList(); }
 }

 this.comboBox1.DataSource = this.A16Games;
 this.comboBox2.DataSource = this.A8Games;
```

Comment: @Martjin van Put, thanks Martin.  This is a valid approach that could be used to sort the list being displayed in the combo box; however, I was more interested in why .NET allowed the initial datasource assignment to work correctly (sorted) on comboBox1, but all other attempts fail.

Comment: @HighExodus, You're welcome! And indeed it has to due with the sorted cannot be set on datasource as in above answer Paul Zaczkowski

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that You can not change data source of sorted combobox.
Here is excerpt of the code of ComboBox control:

```
        protected override void OnDataSourceChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((this.Sorted && (this.DataSource != null)) && base.Created)
        {
            this.DataSource = null;
            throw new InvalidOperationException(System.Windows.Forms.SR.GetString("ComboBoxDataSourceWithSort"));
        }
        ...
        ...
    }
```

In such case You should have received an InvalidOperationException. 
Why didn't You receive ?
Here is the answer:

Implementation of DataSource property in ComboBox control redirects to its base class (ListControl) implementation:

```
        public object DataSource
    {
        get
        {
            return base.DataSource;
        }
        set
        {
            base.DataSource = value;
        }
    }
```

And then in the base class's DataSource:

```
        public object DataSource
    {
        [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
        get
        {
            return this.dataSource;
        }
        set
        {
            if (((value != null) && !(value is IList)) && !(value is IListSource))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(System.Windows.Forms.SR.GetString("BadDataSourceForComplexBinding"));
            }
            if (this.dataSource != value)
            {
                try
                {
                    this.SetDataConnection(value, this.displayMember, false);
                }
                catch
                {
                    this.DisplayMember = "";
                }
                if (value == null)
                {
                    this.DisplayMember = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please, pay attention to the silent **catch** block.
Since SetDataConnection calls OnDataSourceChanged then as far as my analysis is correct this is the reason. If I'm wrong, please correct me.